# Update $state variable in 1 module from another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, angularjs-controller

https://plnkr.co/edit/PWuKuVw9Dn9UJy6l8hZv?p=preview

I have 3 modules, `routerApp`, `tickers` and `tags`. Basically trying to rebuild my app out of smaller mini-apps.

The `routerApp` template contains the 2 directives for the other modules.

### Expected

When you login, then click on the <kbd>Count</kbd> button in the **tickers.component**, I want to send the `counter` var into the **tags.component** `$scope` via `$state.go`.

### Result

Nothing happens. No `$state`/variable update in the tags.component

---

#### Plnkr app.js code:

```
// TICKERS app module
var tickers = angular.module('tickers', ['ui.router'])

tickers.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const tickers = {
    name: 'tickers',
    url: '/tickers',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'tik',
    controller: function() {

    }
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(tickers);
  
})

tickers.component('tickersModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('Tickers init')
    
    $scope.counter = 0;
    
    $scope.increase = function() {
      $scope.counter++;
      console.log('increase', $scope.counter)
      $state.go('dashboard.tags', { counter: $scope.counter });
    }
  }
})

// TAGS app module
var tags = angular.module('tags', ['ui.router'])

tags.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const tags = {
    name: 'tags',
    url: '/tags?counter',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    params: {
      counter: 0
    },
    templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'tags',
    controller: function($state) {

    }
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(tags);
  
})

tags.component('tagsModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    // Expecting this to update:
    console.log('Tags init', $state)
    $scope.counter = $state.params.counter;
  }
})

// MAIN ROUTERAPP module
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router', 'tickers', 'tags']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    const login = {
      name: 'login',
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'l',
      controller: function($state) {
        this.login = function() {
          $state.go('dashboard', {})
        }
      }
    }

    const dashboard = {
      name: 'dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
      controller: function() {
        
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
        .state(login)
        .state(dashboard);

})
```

#### dashboard.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Dashboard</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <tickers-module></tickers-module>
  <tags-module></tags-module>
</div>
```

**The function in the tickers component that is trying to update the $state of the tags component:**

```
$scope.increase = function() {
  $scope.counter++;
  console.log('increase', $scope.counter)
  $state.go('dashboard.tags', { counter: $scope.counter });
}
```

Also tried: `$state.go('tags', { counter: $scope.counter });`

**Finally the tags.component.**
Note that here I'm not seeing the $scope.counter update nor the controller for the component getting refreshed due to a state change.

```
tags.component('tagsModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('Tags init', $state)
    $scope.counter = $state.params.counter;
  }
})
```

**Is the way I am architecting this going to work? What am I missing?**

---

Update: Added some `$rootScope` events to watch for $state changes, hope this helps:

This is after clicking the login button and going from the `login` state to the `dashboard` state, but still nothing for clicking on the <kbd>Count</kbd> button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Figured it out!

https://plnkr.co/edit/CvJLXKYh8Yf5npNa2mUh?p=preview

My problem was that in the $state object tags, I was using the same template as the tags.component.

Instead I needed to change it to something like `<p>{{ counter }}</p>`

```
var tags = angular.module('tags', ['ui.router'])

tags.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const tags = {
    name: 'tags',
    url: '/tags',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    params: {
      counter: 0
    },
    template: '<p>{{ counter }}</p>',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('tags state object', $state)
      $scope.counter = $state.params.counter;
    }
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(tags);
  
})

tags.component('tagsModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tags-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    
  }
})
```

Then in my tags-module.template.html I needed to add a `<div ui-view></div>`

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>Tags list</h2>
    <div ui-view></div> // <- here and this is where the $state object updates
    {{ counter }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you're properly passing the parameters in your $state.go call.

I think the issue here is that you're not properly handling the state parameters you're passing from the tickers component to the tags component.

Try injecting $stateParams into your tags component and pull the parameters off that object, for example (in your tags controller):

```
 $scope.counter = $stateParams.counter;
```

Comment: Ok something strange is happening in this fork: https://plnkr.co/edit/n2RANdhtRYIGQURVIElY?p=preview I'm using `$state.go('tags` on the <kbd>Count</kbd> and the tags.component does not update, but for some reason the tickers and dashboard get inited. Also the counter never goes above 2, and gets reset...